# SQL Server Emergency mode - Syntax incorrect

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I dont know whats the problem with that sql query :

```sql
ALTER DATABASE myDB SET EMERGENCY;
```

i got that error :

> Msg 102, Niveau 15, Etat 6, Ligne 1
> Incorrect syntaxt near 'EMERGENCY';

I use Microsoft SQL Server 2000 - 8.00.760 and SSMD 2016.

Comment: SQL Server 2000? ***WHY***? That is been *completely* unsupported for about a decade. SSMS 2016 also does *not* support SQL Server 2000. I think the "newest" version of SSMS that does is SSMS 2008. As for the error, I no doubt suspect that the syntax you are using didn't exist 21 years ago. With respect, you're about 10 years over due getting that instance on a supported version.

Comment: I don't think you'll find anyone using SQL Server 2000, it's 2021 btw.

Comment: My database is in suspect mode and i want to repair it and that query won't execute do you know why ?

Comment: Looking at the SQL Server 200 [build list](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/#sql2000) as well, 8.00.760 was SP3 (released in 2003). SP4 was released in 2005 and there have been almost 80 updates released since that with security and bug fixes... You're running a version of SQL Server that was released 21 years ago, and has been unpatched for 18; that's (honestly) just asking for trouble.

Comment: *"do you know why"* As I suggested, because it's very likely `SET EMERGENCY` didn't exist in 2000. You're going to be *very* hard pressed to find any documentation that dates back to SQL Server 2000.

Comment: I know, but can i repair the database ?

Comment: Like the documentation, people that are familiar, or more likely were and still remember enough about it, are scarce. And, again, for good reason. SQL Server 2000 has been *long* unsupported.

Comment: Don't waste your time trying to repair it. Restore it from backups. You have working backups, right?

Comment: Dash, I did a ton of SQL the last 30 years and seriously, I am not even considering picking up this question. Why? Because I hardly remember any details of how this ancient version worked. Even less when we talk of something that was ignored and not patched.

Answer (score 1):

> I dont know whats the problem

The issue is that you are using SQL Server 2000. Paul Randal mentions [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-emergency-mode-repair-the-very-very-last-resort/)

> I decided to add a new feature to SQL Server 2005 called EMERGENCY-mode repair that will do steps 2 and 3 as an atomic operation.

So the syntax you are trying to do does not exist in 2000.

The "hacking system tables" he mentions is described [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/recovering-suspectoffline-databases).

But you should be restoring from backup as first resort here.

Comment: Thank you everyone. like AlwaysLearning said 'Don't waste your time trying to repair it. Restore it from backups.' i restored it from backups. I don't have much time to search for solution.

Comment: Thank you @Martin Smith, I will see that soon.